# Keyboard Shortcut key for run

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

I am using Eclipse IDE for java programming. Is there any shortcut key to run codes or I have always have to click the run button?

Comment: Press »CTRL+SHIFT+L« twice to see the list of shortcuts. Source: eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse it's the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

You can see the shortcut if you click in the **Run** item on the toolbar:

[image]